# login as a user and admin at the same time in laravel

Tags: laravel, multiple-users

I am working on a laravel project in which from ADMIN panel I can log in in the user module, but when I want to go back from the browser the admin panel is not working means admin is logout. is there any method in which I can log in in both module admin and user.

Answer (score 0):

If you log in as one user, you log out as the other.
I see 2 possibilities:

1) Make 2 user tables, with separate login/logout/etc. one for your frontend users, one for your admin panel.
The advantage here is that your regular users will never be able to login as an admin, because they don't exist in that table.

2) Separate your frontend and admin panel into 2 different projects. You can link them to the same database. Put the admin panel on a subsite admin.my-project.com.
The advantage here is that you seperate your logic between 2 projects, each focused on different functionality, with their own styling, layout and most important for your example: authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use an incognito browser window for your admin tasks, which will enable you to be logged in to the same app twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem with two possible ways that laravel provide and you could google about "laravel multi auth example".

1. Multiple authentications using "middleware"
2. Multiple authentications using auth "guards"

Here are two articles will help you to understand and show you the implement with an example:

1. [Laravel 6 Multi Auth (Authentication) Tutorial](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-multi-auth-authentication-tutorialexample.html)
2. [How to use multiple authentication guards in a Laravel app](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel)

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am learning laravel. i dont know that where to call the function if i want to go browser back button. i declared one function but dont know where is the right place to call the function if i want to go browser back.

Comment: @swetaramani It's didn't clear much what actually you wanted to do. Could you please give me a summary of what actually you want to do?